# Adicionar um Texto ao Clicar no Botão TKINTER Phyton

Tags: tkinter

[![foto do onde está o botão][1]][1]queria saber se é possível ao clicar no botão aparecer o meu código mostrando o nome e os valores de cada moeda.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfanb.png

````
from tkinter.tix import COLUMN
from wsgiref.validate import validator
import cryptocompare
from tkinter import *


#Function DEF
def crypto_values():
    print(btc,
    eth,
    theter,
    doge,
    solana,
    xrp)


#Values Crypto
btc = cryptocompare.get_price('BTC', currency="BRL")


eth = cryptocompare.get_price('ETH', currency="BRL")


theter = cryptocompare.get_price('USDT', currency="BRL")


doge = cryptocompare.get_price('DOGE', currency="BRL")


solana= cryptocompare.get_price('SOL', currency="BRL")

xrp= cryptocompare.get_price('XRP', currency="BRL")





#Window
window= Tk()
window.title('Cryptocurrency Values')



#Text Sub Tittle
text_orientation = Label(window, text='Click the button to know the values ​​of cryptocurrencies')
text_orientation.grid(column=0 , row=0)



#Button
button = Button(window, text= 'Click here to compare cryptocurrency prices', command=crypto_values)
button.grid (column=0, row=1)

#Text
crypto_values= Label(window, text='')
crypto_values.grid(column=0, row=2)

window.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Seu código tinha dois principais erros:

1º - O comando que você estava usando para que aparecessem os valores, era o "print", e eles estavam aparecendo, mas estavam aparecendo no TERMINAL, porque é isso que o "print" vai fazer. Se você quiser que os valores apareçam no Tkinter, você deve usar funções e métodos do Tkinter pra isso

2º - Você não definiu onde os valores apareceriam na interface gerada pelo Tkinter, abaixo tem a minha alteração do código. Segue o passo a passo das alterações:

1. Perceba que criei uma nova label na linha 29, e depois defini a
   posição dela no programa.
2. Pronto, temos ONDE exibir os valores, mas agora precisamos definir como e quando essa label vai receber os valores.
3. Você já tinha colocado uma command pro botão, então essa parte estava certa, nessa parte eu só mudei o nome da função.
4. Já dentro da Def click, eu usei o método
   `(Nome da Label).configure(text="texto")`
   que essa sim é a função que você deve usar, ao invés de print, lembrando que cada criação do Tkinter **pode** ter métodos diferentes pra modificação, por isso é importante você olhar a documentação.
5. Tudo pronto, só rodar!

PS: Você precisa melhorar essa organização de código

PS²: Já que você já está importando tudo do tkinter (linha 4 do seu código original), não precisava essa importação "from tkinter.tix import COLUMN" na primeira linha, então removi

```
from wsgiref.validate import validator
import cryptocompare
from tkinter import *


#Function click
def click():
    Valores.configure(text=(str(btc) + "\n" + str(eth) + "\n" + str(theter) + "\n" + str(doge) + "\n" + str(solana) + "\n" + str(xrp)))



#Values Crypto
btc = cryptocompare.get_price('BTC', currency="BRL")
eth = cryptocompare.get_price('ETH', currency="BRL")
theter = cryptocompare.get_price('USDT', currency="BRL")
doge = cryptocompare.get_price('DOGE', currency="BRL")
solana= cryptocompare.get_price('SOL', currency="BRL")
xrp= cryptocompare.get_price('XRP', currency="BRL")


#Window
window= Tk()
window.title('Cryptocurrency Values')


#Labels
text_orientation = Label(window, text='Click the button to know the values of cryptocurrencies')
text_orientation.grid(column=0 , row=0)
Valores = Label(window, text="Não há dados disponíveis", font="none 12 bold")
Valores.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Buttons
button = Button(window, text= 'Click here to compare cryptocurrency prices', command=click)
button.grid (column=0, row=1)

#Text
crypto_values= Label(window, text='')
crypto_values.grid(column=0, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```